# How to cancel sliding down animation and make just static slide

Tags: javascript, css

Don't know how to make a static slide , got this sliding down animation.
What should I change?
Maybe I made smth with 'position' property?
Or with positioning in general?
Or my JS sucks....

```
        #slides {
        position: relative;
        height: 500px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .slide {
        width: 600px;
        height: 500px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-left: 500px;
        opacity: 0;
        z-index: 1;
        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
        -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
        -o-transition: opacity 1s;
        transition: opacity 1s;
    }

    .showing {
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    .controls {
        display: none;
    }

    .slide {
        font-size: 40px;
        padding: 70px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: #333;
        color: #fff;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .controls {
        background: #333;
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        padding: 20px 0px;
        font-size: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        margin: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 70px;
        position: relative;
        left: 38%;
        margin-top: 25px;
      }

    .controls:hover,
    .controls:focus {
        background: #eee;
        color: #333;
    }

    .buttons {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        z-index: 20;
        font-size: 0px;
    }

    .controls:nth-of-type(2), .controls:nth-of-type(3) {
        width: 9%;
    }

   // Some JS
    var controls = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
    for(var i=0; i<controls.length; i++){
     controls[i].style.display = 'inline-block';
    }

    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
    var currentSlide = 0;
    var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);

    function nextSlide(){
     goToSlide(currentSlide+1);
    }

   function previousSlide(){
    goToSlide(currentSlide-1);
   }

   function goToSlide(n){
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentSlide = (n+slides.length)%slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
   }


  var playing = true;
  var pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');

  function pauseSlideshow(){
    pauseButton.innerHTML = '&#9658;'; // play character
    playing = false;
    clearInterval(slideInterval);
  }

  function playSlideshow(){
   pauseButton.innerHTML = '&#10074;&#10074;'; // pause character
   playing = true;
   slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);
  }

  pauseButton.onclick = function(){
    if(playing){ pauseSlideshow(); }
    else{ playSlideshow(); }
  };

 var next = document.getElementById('next');
 var previous = document.getElementById('previous');

 next.onclick = function(){
  pauseSlideshow();
  nextSlide();
 };
previous.onclick = function(){
  pauseSlideshow();
  previousSlide();
};
```

Sorry, that it is without comments :(

Comment: None of this is JS. - Saying that, you can animate many different properties. Some properties are better than others. [Check this list](https://gist.github.com/paulirish/5d52fb081b3570c81e3a) of JS properties to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use the `opacity` property to hide the image, it will still "occupy the space" and therefore move the elements down,

You'll need to use the `display` which will simply not draw anything for this element and not allocate any space for it.

In your CSS, replace `opacity: 0` in the .slide by `display: none`

and replace `opacity: 1` in the .showing by `display: block`

It should fix your problem

Comment: Sorry, but it's still sliding down
I want it to be just switched between each other in fixed place

Comment: Alright, could you include a codepen / JSFiddle with your html so that we can see the exact effect you get?

Comment: Alright found the solution i'm editing my awnser now

Comment: You're welcome, come by again if we can help you with anything else :D